# Remove an element from it's parent and append it to other Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parent

I want to remove an element from it's parent and append it to other element. From the start, the code looks like below:

```
<div id="example">
    <div class="photobooth">
        <ul id="capture_options">
           <li>Cpture 1</li>
           <li>Capture 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="option_div">

</div>
```

I want to remove capture_options and append it to a div with an id "option_div". Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: show us your effort?

Comment: Are you basically asking for a dual listbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can do as simple as this:

```js
$(function(){
  
    $('#capture_options').appendTo( $('#option_div') );
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
    <div class="photobooth">
        <ul id="capture_options">test</ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="option_div">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.append()` or `.appendTo()`

```
$('#option_div').append($('#capture_options'));
```